# unable to draw shapes in kivy

Tags: pycharm, kivy

Hlo everyone,
I am Btech final year student
I want to learn android app development through python using kivy
and I am completely new to that
I have started learning through YouTube
i have created a blank window but unable to get the shape in it

**here is my .py code :**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class PongGame(Widget):
    pass

class PongApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return PongGame()

PongApp().run()
```

**and here is my .ky code :
**

```
<PongGame>:
    canvas:

    Rectangle:
        pos:self.center_x, 0
        size : 10, self.height
```

can someone please rectify this

to get the rectangle

Comment: Your `Rectangle` in the `kv` should be indented.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.